# Why xcorr and finddelay are giving different outputs?

Tags: matlab

```
fs = 1.0e4;
 t = 0:1/fs:0.005;
 signal = cos(2*pi*1000*t)'; 
 shifted_signal = delayseq(signal,5); 
 subplot(2,1,1)
 plot(t.*1000,signal) 
 title('Input')
 subplot(2,1,2)
 plot(t.*1000,shifted_signal) 
 title('5 Sample Delay')
 xlabel('msec')
 [c, lags]=xcorr(signal,shifted_signal);
 [A,I]=max(abs(c));
 figure (2)
 plot(lags,c);
 d1=finddelay(signal,shifted_signal);
 d2=lags(I);
```

With xcorr i am getting a delay of -5, with finddelay function i am getting a delay of 0. Why is this happening ?Also why Iam getting '-5' and not '5' with the xcorr ?

Answer (score 1):

The way `xcorr` works ([as stated in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xcorr.html)):

*Cross-correlation measures the similarity between a vector x and shifted (lagged) copies of a vector y as a function of the lag*

So it is pretty normal than the maximum correlation between your two signals is obtained by shifting your `shifted_signal` by a delay of -5.

Concerning [`finddelay`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/finddelay.html), you need to have a full copy of the first signal in the second in order for the function to return you the delay. In your example, the `shifted_signal` is cropped to match the length of your initial signal, so `finddelay` cannot work.